# Paypal Webhook is created sufficient to imply activated

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-webhooks

Paypal with active webhooks. We use a subscription plan.

When a customer
subscribes to the subscription plan PayPal's webhook sends us a `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED`.   We do not get a `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED`. Can I expect it being activated when it is
created or do I need to double check that?

(Side note, when trying to send an api request to activate it, an error message informs me that the subscription plan is not “suspended”. So that looks like it is already activated. Logging into PayPal also confirms it is activated.)

The documentation on it is a little vague.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created means the user clicked the button to subscribe. It does not mean they entered any payment details, or finished subscribing.

If you are not receiving a BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED event but the subscription is active, perhaps you did not subscribe to that event?

In any case, the most useful event to listen for is PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED. This will occur for the first payment as well as every future payment on the schedule. You can build all your business logic with only PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED , using every receipt of this event to mark how long the subscription is valid for in your system (e.g. 1 month from receipt)

Comment: Please clarify how you can build all the business logic using the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED? When I subscribe to my account, I first get the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED, then I get the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED and an hour or more later I get the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED. AS per the following time stamps that I Logged when I retrieved the raw payload: for each webhook... continue on next comment

Comment: *** DATE CREATED ***
**2023-07-16 22:30:17**
{"id":"WH-0KL90264PH880313G-2LJ388088E876452P","event_version":"1.0","create_time":"2023-07-17T03:29:57.626Z", *** DATE CREATED ***
**2023-07-16 22:30:48**
{"id":"WH-79W37639CK624251F-461827347V7942809","event_version":"1.0","create_time":"2023-07-17T03:30:34.303Z", *** DATE CREATED ***
**2023-07-16 23:46:10**
{"id":"WH-0JD67273GP733935J-2MV32827HL281825B","event_version":"1.0","create_time":"2023-07-17T03:30:29.739Z". As you can see, the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED is not reliable for a timely response. How can I fix that?

Comment: PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED is the notification PayPal sends when there is a successful first payment, as well as for all future payments. If you want to poll status separately, you can do so. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869634/paypal-sandbox-webhooks-like-payment-sale-completed-for-subscriptions-very-slow