# Paypals PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETE takes a long time to go through

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have 3 webhooks that I am using for my subscription account.

> BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED
> BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED
> PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED

When I'm running my sandbox account and I have the subscriber subscribe, the webhooks for the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.* show up fairly quickly and sometimes the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED is right there. But there are times where the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED can take up to 15-20 minutes or longer before it shows up in my webhook events.

14 Jul 2023 17:51:33    Billing subscription activated
14 Jul 2023 17:50:48    Billing subscription created
14 Jul 2023 17:33:01    Billing subscription activated
14 Jul 2023 17:32:37    Billing subscription created

Here are two subscriptions that I have done. Note the times. 20 mins had passed between the first and second subscription and there is still no webhook for the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED for either of them.

**Question:**
Are there high traffic times when the responses slow down?

**Question 2:**
When I have a subscriber purchase a subscription, can I utilize the information from the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED and BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED to set up part of their account then hope that I get a response from the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED later on to finish setting up their account? Would that be prudent? If not, should I put a notice or disclaimer stating it could take up to a half an hour or longer for their subscription to become active??

The webhooks don't seem to be very proficient if they are not going to be handled in a matter of seconds rather than half an hour.

**EDIT**
This page was brought to my attention:

[PayPal sandbox webhooks like PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED for subscriptions very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869634/paypal-sandbox-webhooks-like-payment-sale-completed-for-subscriptions-very-slow)

It does answer my question. Now I have another question.

**Question**
I know virtually nothing about javascript. All the javascript sdk's are created for me by paypal. Could someone put some javascript snippets that would do the fetch thing and how would I implement it to my server call? What is the flow and payloads? How would I know which side completes first, i.e. client side vs server side?

Thank You guys.